# Guidance for MS SQL Delete query

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server database there is scenario like database have one primary key and primary key is in format like '0000100001' and 'C100001'

I want to delete the all records from database which starts with '0' but not the records starts with 'C'.

I tried the inbuilt function `SUBSTRING('primary_key',1,1)='0'` but it did not helped me..
Thank You..

Comment: Could you show us your table schema? `SUBSTRING('primary_key', 1, 1)` will apply the substring function to the string "primary_key" and not the intended column.

Comment: those are very poor primary keys by design and this shows the problem.  by combining multiple parts of info into a single column you need to do all these silly string manipulation tricks to delete what you want.  if you had split this into multiple columns you could easily say `WHERE FlagValue='X'` and be on your way.  Also all of your leading zeros will waste storage (string vs. int) and cause many LIKE string searches because users don't like entering in leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING('primary_key',1,1)='0'
```

tests whether the **string literal** `"primary_key"` starts with the character `0` (which it doesn't so will return zero rows), Get rid of the single quotes to reference the column. (NB: If your column is not actually called `primary_key` you will need to reference its actual name of course!)

Or alternatively you can use `WHERE primary_key LIKE '0%'` which can use the index to locate the rows so is more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know MS SQL, but in MySQL it would be something like this:

```
"DELETE * FROM your_table WHERE primary_key LIKE '0%' AND primary_key NOT LIKE 'C%'"
```

You can use the LIKE operator to essentially search for a occurances of either a string or a regular expression. It can take wildcards such as the `%` sign both in front, behind, or both in front and behind of the pattern you are looking for.

For example:

`LIKE 'C%'` would match anything starting with `C`

`LIKE '%C'` would match anything ending in `C`

`LIKE '[A-Z]%'` would match anything starting with a capital letter

`LIKE '%LOL%'` would match anything that has the word `LOL`(in caps) in it.

Further reading at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: This fails because 1. Your answer is for MySQL. 2. It will delete keys starting 1, 2, 3, A, B etc too

Comment: It's very similar, and still helpful. Either way I edited my answer to specify that. Also, he said he wants to keep anything starting with "C". I gave him examples for other scenarios

Comment: The OP states: "I want to delete the all records from database which starts with '0' but not the records starts with 'C'."  NOT LIKE 'C%' is not the same as LIKE '0%' as gbn pointed out. the additional information is useful; but the first part is very bad and could cause harm if they didn't have backups or test it out first.  That's the reason for the downvotes.